# Counterexample to Noether normalization over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

The Noether normalization lemma states that if $k$ is a field and $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, then $A$ is module-finite over a polynomial ring over $k$ (or over $k$ itself). [This generalization](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supNoeth.pdf) shows that if $k$ is replaced with a domain $D$, a finitely generated $D$-algebra $A$ is still module-finite over a polynomial ring over a localization $D_f$ of $D$ (or possibly module-finite over $D_f$ itself). One does need to localize, though: for example, $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is not module-finite over any polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$ itself).

I would like an example that shows the need of localization when the transcendence degree is at least 1 though. It seems to me that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2xy-1)$ is probably an example, but I'm not sure how to prove this:

> Is it true that $A = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2xy-1)$ is not module-finite over any polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$? How would you prove it?

The proof of the generalized Noether normalization lemma given in the link, when applied to this case, leads to the conclusion that $A$ is module-finite over the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[1/2][x]$ over the localization $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, suggesting that inverting $2$ is necessary. But how could we *prove* that there is no element $\alpha\in A$ such that $A$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$-module?

Comment: Why not just take $\mathbb{Z}[1/2][x]$ as your counterexample?

Comment: @KevinCarlson - I think it amounts to the same question. What's the argument that it's not module-finite over a polynomial ring? For example how do you know it's not finite over something like $\mathbb{Z}[x+1/2]$? (Am I missing something obvious?)

Comment: eh, no, I don't think you're missing anything obvious.

Comment: If $A\subset B$ and $B$ is a finitely generated module over $A$, then given a prime ideal of $A$, there is a prime ideal of $B$ lying over the prime in $A$. In your example, if $\mathbb{Z}[t]\subset \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2xy-1)$ with the larger ring a  finite module over the samller one, there is not prime ideal lying over $2\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Comment: @Mohan - ah, because $2\in 2\mathbb{Z}[t]$ generates the unit ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2xy-1)$. This is a complete answer. Might you put it in the form of an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Nice question, Ben!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \subset B$ and $B$ is a finitely generated module over $A$, then given a prime ideal of $A$, there is a prime ideal of $B$ lying over the prime in $A$. In your example, if $\mathbb{Z}[t] \subset \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2xy−1)$ with the larger ring a finite module over the smaller one, there is not prime ideal lying over $2 \mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Comment: (Just to add the step that I didn't see immediately when I read this answer: $2$ is a unit of $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2xy-1)$, thus regardless of $t$,  $2\mathbb{Z}[t]$ generates the unit ideal in $R$, so it is not the contraction of any prime of $R$.

Comment: Nice answer, Mohan! And useful  comment, Ben!